# Программа удаляет пробелы

Tags: java

Всем привет
Я написал программу которая делает анаграмму введенного текста, и проблема в том, что при выводе готовой анаграммы пропадает пробел например: String input = "qwe asd", String completeAnagram = "ewqdsa"

```
public String reverseWords(String input) {
    String oneOrMoreSpaces = "\\s";
    String[] words = input.split(oneOrMoreSpaces);
    String completeAnagram = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        char[] symbol = words[i].toCharArray();
        char newSymbolSequence;
        int j = symbol.length - 1, k = 0;

        while (k < j) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(symbol[k]))
                k++;
            else if (!Character.isLetter(symbol[j]))
                j--;
            else {
                newSymbolSequence = symbol[k];
                symbol[k] = symbol[j];
                symbol[j] = newSymbolSequence;
                k++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        completeAnagram = completeAnagram + new String(symbol;
    }
    return completeAnagram;
}
```

Помогите исправить

Answer (score 0):

```
completeAnagram += new String(symbol) + " "; // вы можете добавлять пробел после каждого слова (прошедшего обработку)
```

при возвращении результата не забудьте удалить последний пробел

Comment: тогда получается так 
input: "asd dsa"
output: "asd dsa "

Comment: @marzocchi из-за прибавления пробела не может так измениться вывод

Comment: необходимо что бы сохранялся только тот пробел, который уже имеется, а не добавлялся после каждого следующего

Comment: @marzocchi, вы первоначально разделили строку на массив слов, я предлагаю просто после каждого обработанного слова вставлять пробел

Comment: тогда unit test показывает ошибку при:
String actual = anagram.reverseWords("qwe123")
String expected = "ewq123"
assertEquals(actual, expected)

Comment: @marzocchi, я ведь предупреждал насчет последнего пробела. сделайте  `return completeAnagram.trim();`

Comment: @marzocchi, я протестировал у себя и при `"qwe123"` я получаю `"ewq123"`, а при `qwe asd` результат `ewq dsa`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String reverseWords(String input) {
    String oneOrMoreSpaces = "\\s";
    String[] words = input.split(oneOrMoreSpaces);
    StringBuilder completeAnagram = new StringBuilder();
    for (String word : words) {
        char[] symbol = word.toCharArray();
        char newSymbolSequence;
        int j = symbol.length - 1, k = 0;
        while (k < j) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(symbol[k]))
                k++;
            else if (!Character.isLetter(symbol[j]))
                j--;
            else {
                newSymbolSequence = symbol[k];
                symbol[k] = symbol[j];
                symbol[j] = newSymbolSequence;
                k++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        completeAnagram.append(new String(symbol)).append(" ");
    }
    return completeAnagram.toString().trim();
}
```